# How to list all tags in Asana

Tags: asana

How do I get a list of all the tags in an Asana project?

(I feel silly for not being able to figure out something so trivially basic, but I can't find it anywhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ability to view all tags has been removed.  You could create a task in a project titled "tags", then list all the tags in that task.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-display-all-of-my-tags-in-Asana
https://asana.com/guide/help/tasks/fields#gl-tags